# determine whether listbox items are visible in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

On a list box, if the user clicks the little button at the side of the box, the options are displayed.  In selenium, is there a way to determine whether that list of options is visible to the user or not.  (In selenium the isDisplayed() method will return true for items in a drop down list, even if the option is not visible to the eye.)  For example, I'd like to be able to distinguish between the two states of the list box, as shown in the following two images.  In the first, the list box is closed, in the second, it is open.

[image: list box closed]

[image: list box open]

Comment: Can you please post the html of the first and second screenshots. I am sure we can find it out, there should be a div or modal which is holding all 4 options shown in the 2nd screenshot.

Comment: The html for both images is exactly the same, straight up list box.

<body>
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
 </body>

Comment: Can you please share the link, if it's possible?

Comment: Just a thought, can you get the `x` and `y` of the option before and after clicking the listbox.

Comment: Here is the page I pulled those images/html from.  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select.  I tried getting the x and y of the <option> element, using .getLocation() and .getLocation().getX() etc, but these just return '0'.